# asp:RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: asp.net, html, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

So the user clicks on a hyperlink 'add data' which brings them to a new page where they will have to enter text into 3 textboxes and then click the button.
When the button is clicked (an error msg will show-if one of the text boxes is left empty)

I've tried

```
 <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" MaxLength="20" />
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="ValidationTextBox1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Please enter" />
             </td>
```

but when i test this, empty no data into the text box and click the button I receive no error?? please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Required Field Validator control, not the Regular Expression one.

```
 <asp:TextBox id="Text1" 
      Text="Enter a value" 
      runat="server"/>

 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"  
      ControlToValidate="Text1"
      Text="Required Field!" 
      runat="server"/>
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbw267h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Although it's quite difficult to understand the question, i assume that i know the problem.

> when i test this, empty no data into the text box and click the button
>   I receive no error

So the validator does not fire when the `TextBox` is empty?

Use an additional `RequiredFieldValidator` if you want to validate empty text.

> The RegularExpressionValidator does not perform validation on an empty
>   string. To test for an empty string, use the RequiredFieldValidator
>   and RegularExpressionValidator controls together.

[`RegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.mobilecontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.validationexpression.aspx)